# Why should I use "setSeed()" in my java card program?

Tags: java, random, javacard, random-seed

I wrote the below program to generate a *16 byte* random number in my java card. I used the apdu buffer as the seed :

```
public class RandomNumber extends Applet {

    private RandomData rngRandom;
    public static byte[] testArray1=new byte[16];

    private RandomNumber() {
    }

    public static void install(byte bArray[], short bOffset, byte bLength)
            throws ISOException {
        new RandomNumber().register();


    }

    public void process(APDU arg0) throws ISOException {

        byte[] buffer=arg0.getBuffer();
        // CREATE RNG OBJECT
        m_rngRandom = RandomData.getInstance(RandomData.ALG_SECURE_RANDOM);
        m_rngRandom.setSeed(buffer, (short)0,(short)buffer.length );
        // GENERATE RANDOM BLOCK WITH 16 BYTES
        m_rngRandom.generateData(testArray1, (short) 0, (short)16); 

        Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(testArray1, (short)0, buffer, (short)0,(short) testArray1.length);
        arg0.setOutgoingAndSend((short)0, (short)16);

    }

}
```

I convert it and upload it on my card with AID=`01020304050607080900`. 
It works fine for me. I send the SELECT APDU command repeatedly (so I have a fixed seed) and I receive different numbers as the random output :

```
OpenSC: opensc-tool -s 00a404000b0102030405060708090000
Using reader with a card: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
Sending: 00 A4 04 00 0B 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 00
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00):
C2 BA 8E 75 67 A4 5F 16 1C 82 BE 98 5B 95 88 23 ...ug._.....[..#

OpenSC: opensc-tool -s 00a404000b0102030405060708090000
Using reader with a card: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
Sending: 00 A4 04 00 0B 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 00
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00):
8C 95 C3 AC 26 91 97 68 84 57 D8 E9 A5 5A CF 49 ....&..h.W...Z.I

OpenSC: opensc-tool -s 00a404000b0102030405060708090000
Using reader with a card: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
Sending: 00 A4 04 00 0B 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 00
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00):
34 2C 20 17 80 D1 EC 10 E3 E3 08 E2 DB 82 39 CB 4, ...........9.

OpenSC: opensc-tool -s 00a404000b0102030405060708090000
Using reader with a card: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
Sending: 00 A4 04 00 0B 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 00
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00):
E1 F6 60 B9 07 34 F2 46 A2 B0 43 19 E3 37 35 5D ..`..4.F..C..75]

OpenSC:
```

Now, I remove the `setSeed()` method from my program and I upload the new *cap* file. The output is still random :

```
OpenSC: opensc-tool -s 00a404000b0102030405060708090000
Using reader with a card: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
Sending: 00 A4 04 00 0B 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 00
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00):
67 1E AE 42 29 ED 4E EE 0E 8F 57 86 C8 8F A3 FF g..B).N...W.....

OpenSC: opensc-tool -s 00a404000b0102030405060708090000
Using reader with a card: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
Sending: 00 A4 04 00 0B 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 00
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00):
B8 D9 7F 0A EB 3B C3 E4 E0 4C 8F 04 95 E2 1B F4 .....;...L......

OpenSC: opensc-tool -s 00a404000b0102030405060708090000
Using reader with a card: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
Sending: 00 A4 04 00 0B 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 00
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00):
F3 34 88 E4 C2 B1 E9 D1 77 E3 69 4C 91 21 13 69 .4......w.iL.!.i

OpenSC: opensc-tool -s 00a404000b0102030405060708090000
Using reader with a card: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
Sending: 00 A4 04 00 0B 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 00
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00):
69 46 C7 0E C9 81 9E 48 AF 5E D4 6A 28 BF 42 E4 iF.....H.^.j(.B.
```

**My question :**

As you see above, in both cases (using `setSeed()` or not using it) my output is a random array. So why I need to use this method?

Shouldn't I receive the same outcome, when I use a fixed seed? If so, why I don't?

And what is the difference between a fixed seed and a one time seem per generation?

And what is the seed when I don't use this method?

Comment: If you set the seed, roll the dice and set the seed again (to the same value), you will get the same outcome. Can be useful for rigging games.

Comment: @StephanBijzitter I don't receive the same outcome with a fixed seed! It is different every time that I invoke the `process()` method!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setSeed()` supplements rather than replaces the seed for a Java Card `RandomData` object, just like `SecureRandom` on Java SE. This is however not made explicit in the API up to 3.0.4.

However, if you read the text of the constant `ALG_PSEUDO_RANDOM` you'll get:

> Utility pseudo-random number generation algorithms. The random number sequence generated by this algorithm need not be the same even if seeded with the same seed data.

As for the `setSeed` method, *you don't need to call it* and *if you do call it* I would hope that you would call it with a source containing more entropy than the APDU send to the card.

---

In general the distinction of `ALG_PSEUDO_RANDOM` and `ALG_SECURE_RANDOM` is not that clear. `ALG_PSEUDO_RANDOM` could mean that the algorithm is *not as secure as `ALG_SECURE_RANDOM`*, but it could also mean that it is a *pre-seeded deterministic random number generator*.

The same goes for `ALG_SECURE_RANDOM`. You could read that it is the random number generator that is generally available on the chip (after whitening) or it could again mean that it is a *pre-seeded deterministic random number generator* (sounds familiar?) because that's generally thought of to be more secure by the likes of NIST.

If you read this correctly it does mean that both algorithms **may** actually point to the same implementation.

---

All in all, the fact that you don't see much of a difference (just random data) is the expected result. You may see a difference if you run the full set of FIPS sets on the random number generator - it depends on the implementation.

EDIT: As the meaning and the seeding of `ALG_PSEUDO_RANDOM` is not clear, I would advice to use `ALG_SECURE_RANDOM` over `ALG_PSEUDO_RANDOM` to retrieve cryptographically secure random numbers.

*In general* either of the algorithms is pre-seeded by randomness obtained from the security processor of the CPU. This means you cannot use the algorithms to create the same result even if you do supply it the seed. This is good since you don't know the actual algorithm. If you want to do this you may have to program a stream cipher, DRBG or KDF yourself.

Comment: Is there any way to get the seed and save it in an array for example? (That one generated by the card, not the one that I give it)

Comment: No not that I know of. Everybody I've spoken to seems to agree that the rng should be used for generating random values only.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see the source of your class `RandomData`, but I'll assume that you're using a `SecureRandom`. `SecureRamdom` is always seeded randomly and the seed cannot be forced to take a value (otherwise it wouldn't be secure!).

The following is taken from the `SecureRandom.setSeed()` [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html#setSeed%28byte%5B%5D%29)

> **public void setSeed(byte[] seed)**
>
> Reseeds this random object. **The given seed supplements, rather than
>   replaces**, the existing seed. Thus, repeated calls are guaranteed never
>   to reduce randomness.

If you want repeatable "randomness" you need to use a standard [`Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) object.

Comment: So why they provide a `setSeed()` method? I took a look at **javacard 3.0.1 classic edition specifications**. As you said I defined the _algorithm= ALG_SECURE_RANDOM_ in the line `m_rngRandom = RandomData.getInstance(RandomData.ALG_SECURE_RANDOM);` but when I replaced the algorithm with `ALG_PSEUDO_RANDOM`, Nothing changed!

Comment: The wrote in the specification for this second algorithm "Utility pseudo-random number generation algorithms. The random number sequence generated by this 
algorithm need not be the same even if seeded with the same seed data. 
Even if a transaction is in progress, the update of the internal state shall not participate in the transaction." So what is the difference between `ALG_SECURE_RANDOM` and `ALG_PSEUDO_RANDOM`? Why we need `setSeed`?

Comment: And this is a javacard program. the `RandomData` is a class that defined in the package! (so I can't see the source also). moreover, the `Random` object didn't implemented in Java Card APIs

Comment: This is clearly targeting the Java SE API, which is significantly different from the Java Card API.